# Pullback of homology via "trace" and Poincaré duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of compact Riemann surfaces (in particular smooth orientable compact manifolds of dimension 2). Denote the degree by $d$. We have a natural pushforward $H_i(f)$ in homology. I also want a pullback of homology, and I can think of two ways to do that:

- the composition $H_i(Y) \xrightarrow{\text{Poincaré duality}} H^{2-i}(Y) \xrightarrow{\text{natural cohomology pullback}} H^{2-i}(X) \xrightarrow{\text{Poincaré duality}} H_i(X)$
- the "trace map" induced by: For a path in $Y$, take all the $d$ primages of the start point, and lift the path with those starting points. Then add those paths (in the chain group), which should give you a cycle (?!), and hence a homology class.

My question is: Are those two maps the same?

Comment: Maybe it's also worth remarking that the first construction works even when $X$ and $Y$ do not have the same dimension, but then does shift the homology degree by the difference in dimensions. A special case to think about in each direction: (i) embeddings (ii) fiber bundles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are the same and what you call the trace map (and its dual in cohomology) is often called the *transfer* homomorphism. I will generalize to $X$ and $Y$ oriented triangulable closed $n$-manifolds but assume that $f : X \to Y$ is a degree $d$ *covering* map to ensure that the basepoint does have $d$ preimages. With this assumption it is easy to check that the transfer map on chains commutes with taking boundaries, so does produce a map on homology. With some more care you can also make it work for branched covers. Denote the transfer or trace map by $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} \tr : H_*(Y) \to H_*(X)$.

Let $\alpha \in H^k(Y)$. Note that if $\sigma \in C_k(Y)$ and $\sigma'$ is any lift in $C_k(X)$ then by definition $f_*(\sigma') = \sigma$, so $f^*(\alpha)(\sigma') = \alpha(\sigma)$.
From this it follows that for $h \in H_*(Y)$ (possibly assuming $* \ge k$ depending on how general your definitions are),
$$\tr(h \frown \alpha) = \tr(h) \frown f^*(\alpha).$$
Taking $h = [Y]$ (the fundamental class of $Y$) you get
$$\tr[Y] \frown f^*(\alpha) = \tr([Y] \frown \alpha).$$
This is exactly what you want once we verify that $\tr[Y] = [X]$. But if you start with a triangulation of $Y$ and pull back to $X$ then both $\tr[Y]$ and $[X]$ are just the sum of all the oriented top-dimensional simplices in $X$.

As a remark, one advantage of the Poincaré duality definition of this wrong-way or *Umkehr* map is that it works for any continuous map of oriented closed manifolds, or even more generally any proper continuous map of oriented manifolds.

Comment: Thank you very much!